# CucumberJS - Is there a way to get scenario background information from hook?

Tags: cucumberjs

CucumberJS - Is there a way to get scenario background information from hook?

I already checked in the `ast/step.js`, `ast/scenario.js` & `ast/feature.js`, it seems that it was ripped from `feature.js` on [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/commit/a5fd8251918c278ab2e389226d165cedb44df14a#diff-5530e5c6e19e6191a22488fb10c9819b) commit:

Is there another way to get the background information?

Right now it is merging all the background steps into the steps information but this is not practical if you need to know wether they are part of the background or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of CucumberJS (3.x - present) you can access all details of the current scenario in the `Before` hook using the [pickle object from Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin#pickles):

```js
Before(function ({ pickle }) {
    // ... add whatever information you need to the World object here.
});
```

Live Demonstration: https://testjam.io/?p=od8QsClhFjmZB6zOsEyI